# UWP StateTrigger Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I am writing a UWP app that uses Visual States, and I am having issues with binding `IsActive` on a `StateTrigger`.

We are using MVVM, and I need to be able to change the state of a VisualState.

My current example:

### XAML

```
<Page
   ...
   >

    <Page.Resources>
        <local:InvBoolConverter x:Key="InvBoolConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="MainGrid">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="textSwitcher">
                <VisualState>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding IsRedTrigger, Converter={StaticResource InvBoolConverter}}" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="txtBlock.Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding IsRedTrigger}" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="txtBlock.Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>


        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button Content="Switch" Command="SwitchClickCommand" />
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlock" Margin="100" Foreground="Blue">My Text</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

### View Model

```
namespace ...
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase
    {

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            SwitchClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(_SwitchButtonClicked);
        }

        public readonly ICommand SwitchClickCommand;

        bool _IsRedTrigger;

        public bool IsRedTrigger
        {
            get { return _IsRedTrigger; }
            set
            {
                _IsRedTrigger = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        void SwitchButtonClicked()
        {
            IsRedTrigger = !IsRedTrigger;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be working properly except the VisualState does not actually change.

Am I using `StateTrigger` correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post  the code of your `BindableBase`? It is triggered by `IsRedTrigger`, did you complete the work with `INotiftpropertyChanged` in this `BindableBase`?

Comment: I am using Prism's `BindableBase`, found: [https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Mvvm/BindableBase.cs](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Mvvm/BindableBase.cs). So yes, it is completed correctly with `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and it is being triggered correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, you didn't mention that you used Prism for development, now I can understand your question.

`Command="SwitchClickCommand"` can not be used because:

> Cannot assign text value `SwitchClickCommand` into property `Command` of type `Icommand`.

I can understand this may be typo since you want to clear your code in the post. I guess the problem is actually that you didn't correctly set the `DataContext` of the page. After doing this, your code works perfectly by my side:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:InvBoolConverter x:Key="InvBoolConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MainPageViewModel x:Name="vm" />
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="MainGrid">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="textSwitcher">
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding IsRedTrigger, Converter={StaticResource InvBoolConverter}}" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="txtBlock.Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding IsRedTrigger}" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="txtBlock.Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Content="Switch" Command="{x:Bind vm.SwitchClickCommand}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlock" Margin="100" Foreground="Blue">My Text</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

And I changed your code `SwitchClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(_SwitchButtonClicked);` to `SwitchClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(SwitchButtonClicked);`, is this also a typo?

By the way, I'm using Prism 6.0, and my os version is 10586.